# How impulse relates to momentum? is this correct?

Tags: momentum

Knowing that:

$$F=\frac{dp}{dt}$$

I manipulate the equation a bit to say:

$$Fdt=dp$$

Then ingrate both sides...

$$\int{F}dt = p$$

From what I've read, isn't the change in momentum related to the impulse? not just the momentum? I have a good feeling what I wrote above is incorrect as that's like saying the momentum is equal to the impulse which isn't true right?

Comment: You are missing the word 'change' .Change in momentum is impulse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its the change in momentum, you should do definite integrals in order to make this work, like so:

$$\int_{t_i}^{t_f}F dt = \int_{p_i}^{p_f} dp = p_f-p_i = \Delta p$$

When taking indefinite integrals, you need to remember that there is an arbitrary constant added until the initial and final conditions have been specified.